# Embedding manifolds with boundary into Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory

Whitney proved that any n-dimensional manifold $M^{n}$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (as a codimension $n$ submanifold). A similar argument can be used to show that any $n$-dimensional CW complex also embeds into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

I am interested in the following related question. Suppose $M^{2n}$ is a $2n$-dimensional manifold with boundary. When can it embed into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$?

There are two obvious necessary conditions. First, $M^{2n}$ must be parallelizable (since $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is). Second, the intersection form on $M$ must vanish.
I will further assume that $M^{2n}$ has the homotopy type of an $(n-1)$-dimensional CW complex, so that Whitney's theorem allows this CW complex to embed into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. I believe that these conditions are sufficient: any parallelizable $M^{2n}$ with boundary and homotopy type of an $n-1$-dimensional CW complex embeds into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Are there any existing results in this direction?

Clarification: I mean that the manifolds are smooth and compact with boundary, and embeddings are smooth.

Comment: The case where $M$ is compact and $n=1$ is well known: the necessary conditions that $M$ be orientable and that the intersection form vanishes is also sufficient. Also, the necessary condition that the $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-valued intersection form vanish is sufficient. Surfaces of this type are sometimes called "genus $0$ surfaces".

Comment: Do you assume compactness of $M$? Otherwise, it is surely false.

Comment: You should also specify if you are working in smooth or topological category, or maybe you mean smooth manifolds but topological embeddings.

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes, I added a clarification.

Comment: Smale-Hirsch theory shows that under the conditions you give, $M^{2n}$ immerses in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.